# Unable to start unetbootin

Tags: unetbootin

When trying to start unetbootin from the terminal using `unetbootin`, I get the following output:

```
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(unetbootin:2244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
(gksu:2256): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed
```

I get the prompt asking for my password but then nothing happens and when started using `sudo unetbootin`, the output is:

```
unetbootin: cannot connect to X server
```

I have tried the following, but to no avail:

- [Bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+bug/1086748)
- [Seemed to be a similar problem](http://forumubuntusoftware.info/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=5955)

I am unable to report the version of unetbootin as neither `unetbootin -v` nor `unetbootin --version` are valid options and the man page does not information on doing this.

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did not resolve until this answer was written, but the main purpose of me using unetbootin was to make a Windows bootable, which can be done using winusb.

To install winusb:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

It has a very intuitive UI, so making a windows bootable shouldn't be hard.