# Trying to get unetbootin to write a Windows ISO on latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: usb, windows, unetbootin

I downloaded a Windows ISO file, and I want to install it on a USB flash drive through Ubuntu. However I can't seem to get unetbootin to pop up. I've tried everything. I also tried using another program and got it to write it to the USB, however it took 12 hours for a 3gb file? When I finally rebooted, and selected *load from flash drive*, it would just start loading up Ubuntu again.

I just want a copy of Windows on my new computer, but I need to either get unetbootin to work, or else get an alternative to work.

Comment: It is possible to install Win XP on a flash drive but I have not heard of a way to run Win 7 or 10 from a flash drive. If you just want to make a Win 10 installer drive see https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-usb-bootable-media-uefi-support

Answer (score 0):

With the information given, I guess the reason your system did not detect your Bootable Windows USB at the start might be because of the `software` you have used to make a bootable USB. The software was unable to create the required boot files while writing the `Windows` to your USB

And I found it really weird that a software took 12 hours, to make a Bootable Windows USB.

My suggestion would be to use a different alternatives of the software. You can find few alternatives [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435432/are-there-alternatives-to-unetbootin).

And also, do remember to change the boot order of your system from your BIOS. You can find more information about it [here](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-boot-order-in-bios-2624528)

Hope this helps :)

PS:- Please share more information about the software you have used in the question. It will be help people give a better answer to your question.